# Engine Code P1312 on 2001 Saab 9-3

Tags: engine, saab

I have replaced to brand new spark plugs.
After some research, it seems that the problem might be the direct ignition cassette.
Could there be other possibilities?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the correct spark plugs, or aftermarket? OEM makes a huge difference in certain vehicle brands.